# What would be the correct way to title an event, where I am about to introduce several projects - "project intro" vs. "projects intro"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

To elaborate just a little bit: there seem to be well-known cases where a similarly built phrase obviously refers to multiple instances of something, whereas the noun is used in its singular form still, e.g. "human rights" - obviously, we are talking about rights of *multiple* humans, not just *one*, although this singular form would seemingly imply exactly that. By that logic I should go with "project intro", even if I am talking about *multiple* projects here. However, what got me thinking, is this: suppose you receive a meeting invite titled "Project intro" - how do you know then if it's about one or many projects, if you lack the context?

Or, maybe, there's some other way to convey the meaning I want, being clear that I'm introducing  more than one project, and keeping the phrase concise (i.e., suitable for e-mail subject line or meeting invite)?

Comment: I would understand _human rights_ to mean the rights of the human species, not a reference to multiple human beings. I would keep _projects_ plural.

Comment: It's not obvious to me why you would care about "correct pluralisation" in a context where you're quite happy to use ***intro*** instead of ***introduction***. But ***project*** as used before ***intro*** is a *noun adjunct* usage. Noun adjuncts are nearly always singular, even if the *main* noun they modify is a plural form such as ***project introductions*** or ***car radios***..